# How to set up YAML file for environment-specific configuration settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, yaml

Currently, I have a session login method that has environment-specific configurations.

```
def log_in(user)
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = { :value => user.remember_token, :domain => :all }
end
```

the `:domain =>` differs between `:all` for production and `'lvh.me'` for development.

How can I set up a YAML file that loads the environment-specific configurations, as shown in [RailsCast #85](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file)?

I tried the code below, but get back `unitialized constant RAILS_ENV`

**app_config.yml**

```
development:
  domain: lvh.me
test:
  domain: :all
production:
  domain:  :all
```

load_app_config.rb

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(::Rails.root.join('config','app_config.yml'))[RAILS_ENV]
```

Comment: Replace with `Rails.env`

Comment: Thanks apneadiving. Looks like it is loading, but I can't get it to load correctly. The exact line I need in development is `:domain => 'lvh.me'`. I've replaced that with `:domain => APP_CONFIG[:domain]`, and tried variations of `domain: lvh.me`, `domain: 'lvh.me'` and `domain: lvh.me:3000` under development in the YAML file but they don't give me the correct cross-domain session I need. Do you know what the correct phrasing would be in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I went with:

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/app_config.yml")[Rails.env].symbolize_keys!
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [confu](https://github.com/underlog/confu) gem. It's very similar to what you're trying to do.